# Speed up EF5 Code First query

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Following on from previous questions using EF5 Code First, SQL Server 2008 R2 db, Generic Repository and Unit Of Work patterns

I have the following function

```
public static void MoveGraphicPosition(int queueId, int graphicId, bool moveUp)
{
    using (var unitOfWork = new GraphicUnitOfWork(ConnGraphics, false))
    {
        var sourceGraphic = unitOfWork.GraphicRepository.FindSingle(g => g.Id == graphicId);

        if (sourceGraphic == null) return;

        var startPosition = sourceGraphic.QueuePosition;

        Graphic targetGraphic;

        if (moveUp)
        {
            targetGraphic =
                unitOfWork.PlayoutQueueRepository.FindSingle(q => q.Id == queueId, q => q.Graphics)
                          .Graphics.Where(g => g.QueuePosition < startPosition)
                          .OrderByDescending(g => g.QueuePosition)
                          .Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            targetGraphic =
                unitOfWork.PlayoutQueueRepository.FindSingle(q=> q.Id == queueId, q => q.Graphics)
                          .Graphics.Where(g => g.QueuePosition > startPosition)
                          .OrderBy(g => g.QueuePosition)
                          .Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        // Swop the positions
        if (targetGraphic == null) return;

        sourceGraphic.QueuePosition = targetGraphic.QueuePosition;

        targetGraphic.QueuePosition = startPosition;

        unitOfWork.GraphicRepository.Update(sourceGraphic);
        unitOfWork.GraphicRepository.Update(targetGraphic);

        // Save to database
        unitOfWork.Save();
    }
}
```

Running this method via a Web Api call it takes about 2 seconds to run, I am bit puzzled as to why it takes this long, was expecting less than a second, is there any advice as to speed this up.

All we are trying to do is change queue positions of two graphic objects - swop queue positions around - our current one with the next one in the queue based on position.

Not sure whether this is EF5 or my LINQ query being inefficient.

FindSingle on the repository looks like this

```
public T FindSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
    var set = FindIncluding(includes);
    return (predicate == null) ? set.FirstOrDefault() : set.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
} 

public IQueryable<T> FindIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable<T> set = _context.GetEntitySet<T>();

    if (includeProperties != null)
    {
        foreach (var include in includeProperties)
        {
            set = set.Include(include);
        }
    }

    return set.AsQueryable();
}
```

I have a feeling might have to change this to take two objects in and then just do the update but this may be masking a problem which we will have to address at a later date as this should be straightforward.

Comment: is this the first think you are doing with EF when you are running the app? If so, you maybe be experiencing startup costs for EF which can be reduced in a number of ways. Eg i fyou are using code first, you can turn off db initialization. You can pregenerate the mapping views to avoid that. First thing to do though is trigger that call a few times. See if it's much faster the second time.

Comment: How does `FindSingle` look like? It looks like you're doing a lot of db queries here. You should try merging them into one if possible.

Comment: Julie, this is not our first call and we have run this query several times and it is always around the two sec

Comment: marcin - just added the extra code parts

Comment: You are loading the full `Graphics` collection and then `Take` only one element in memory. Is the `Graphics` collection so small that you don't expect any significant overhead by this procedure (which is inefficient for larger collections)?

Comment: I thought you were my boss, hehe. We are having the same 'lag' since day 1 working with EF/Code First. The first 'journey' to SQL takes approximately 2s, then it catches up. @JulieLerman, can you give us some examples - or a Chapter of one of your books - of how to implement such calls?

Comment: Unrelated to performance but more for readability and maintainability, I'd recommend to rework `moveUp` to use a single query with some trick to choose sort order basing on the variable. For example, use `SinlgeOrDefault()` or `LastOrDefault()`. You duplicate the main query, this shouldn't be acceptable.

Comment: Tico start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327(v=vs.110).aspx  (and keep i mind that we shouldn't derail this thread if Mark's issue is not about startup)

Comment: If Findincluding is returing a queryable, is the full query (icluding that final Take(1) being executed on the database or, as Slauma suggests, are you pulling back all of the related graphics and then filtering in memory. Once you are past startup costs, I always recommend profiling the database when you've got EF query perf issues. That quickly identifies or rules out something certain possibilities. It might help you see that you are returning many graphics, not one.

Comment: hi - thanks for the responses - tracked it down, it was the notification service we have setup on the save call (so other services/apps no what has been changed on the database) - this was causing an exception which increased the delay, once we put in the correct ip, the delay was around 0.7ms which is what i was expecting.

Comment: In answer to your other questions, I will change the Linq query as advised as i thought there must be a better way of doing it.

Comment: The graphics collection is going to be small, we are pulling them all back in memory and then taking 1. Tico, What we have found is that using EF Code First is that on average it takes around 0.7 - 1 sec to execute no matter what volume of data we chuck at it, the issue we found was having to deal with Linq, if you do the Linq queries right then the speed is excellent.

Comment: Tico, if you are starting out would look at doing Generic Repository and Unit Of Work Patterns - the problem is that there is some many ways of doing this, what I wanted was to have best way explained using code first with these patterns.  Also if starting would do the index migrations first and also default values can not be set via migrations yet (using EF5).

Answer (score 0):

It was the notification service we have setup on the save call (so other services/apps know what has been changed on the database) - this was causing an exception which increased the delay, once we put in the correct IP, the delay was around 0.7ms which is what I was expecting